# Cannot locate BeanDefinitionDecorator for element [property-placeholder]

Tags: xml, spring

I am trying to load the properties file in Spring stand alone project and i am facing lot of struggle.

I am having spring.xml file as below and trying to load config.properties file which has DB Url, user id, password etc.,

Note: com.ioc.collections.PropertyClassDepInj.resources is the package where my spring.xml and config.properties are there.

Spring.xml

```
<bean id="pojoClassA" class="com.ioc.collections.PropertyClassDepInj.PojoClassA">

    <!-- java.util.Properties -->
    <property name="propObj">
        <props>
            <prop key="admin">admin@nospam.com</prop>
            <prop key="support">support@nospam.com</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config.properties" 
            ignore-unresolvable="true" />
    <!--  
    <util:properties id="pp" location="classpath:com.ioc.collections.PropertyClassDepInj.resources.config.properties">

    </util:properties>
 -->

</bean>
```

When i am running main class, i am facing the below exception.

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionDecorator for element [property-placeholder]

I googled many threads related to this, but still it's not clear. I want to understand the root cause of this exception and how to fix this error?

Also, need to know how to use the

How to set the classpath for a particular project within a package in eclipse?

How to inject the properties values like DB Url, DB Password etc., from properties to POJO classes through spring.xml file? Full sample code would be really great!

Comment: I got the answer and it's fixed. I would like to share the same. Actually, the <util:properties tag should be within <properties tag.                                                         <property name="pp">
   <util:properties location="classpath:com/ioc/collections/PropertyClassDepInj/resources/config.properties">
   </util:properties>
  </property>

Comment: Thanks. This one helps me.